# Generic Airflow data staging operator

Tags: airflow

I am trying to understand how to manage large data with Airflow. The documentation is clear that we need to use external storage, rather than XCom, but I can not find any clean examples of staging data to and from a worker node.

My expectation would be that there should be an operator that can run a staging in operation, run the main operation, and staging out again.

Is there such a Operator or pattern? The closes I've found is an [S3 File Transform](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.9/_api/airflow/operators/s3_file_transform_operator/index.html) but it runs an executable to do the transform, rather than a generic Operator, such as a DockerOperator which we'd want to use.

Other "solutions" I've seen rely on everything running on a single host, and using known paths, which isn't a production ready solution.

Is there such an operator that would support data staging, or is there a concrete example of handling large data with Airflow that doesn't rely on each operator being equipped with cloud coping capabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. Traditionally, Airflow is mostly orchestrator - so it does not usually "do" the stuff, it usually tells others what to do. You very rarely need to bring actual data to Airflow worker, Worker is mostly there to tell others where the data is coming from, what to do with it and where to send it.

There are exceptions (some transfer operators actually download data from one service and upload it to another) - so the data passes through Airflow node, but this is an exception rather than a rule (the more efficient and better pattern is to invoke an external service to do the transfer and have a sensor to wait until it completes).

This is more of "historical" and somewhat "current" way how Airflow operates, however with Airflow 2 and beyond we are expandingh this and it becomes more and more possible to do a pattern similar to what you describe, and this is where XCom play a big role there.

You can - as of recently -  develop Custom XCom Backends that allow for more than meta-data sharing - they are also good for sharing the data. You can see docs here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html#custom-backends but also you have this nice article from Astronomer about it https://www.astronomer.io/guides/custom-xcom-backends and a very nice talk from Airflow Summit 2021 (from last week) presenting that: https://airflowsummit.org/sessions/2021/customizing-xcom-to-enhance-data-sharing-between-tasks/ . I Highly Recommend to watch the talk!

Looking at your pattern - XCom Pull is staging-in, Operator's execute() is operation and XCom Push is staging-out.

This pattern will be reinforced, I think by upcoming Airflow releases and some cool integrations that are coming. And there will be likely more cool data sharing options in the future (but I think they will all be based on - maybe slightly enhanced - XCom implementation).